# How to append new records to existing records in a jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I am populating Grid2 from the records selected from Grid1. however The records added are getting replaced by the new set of records from Grid1 whenever i select and add again. below is my code. This is only for the UI. I thought of appending the new records as below. Please guide with the correct code

```
 function StuffData(data) {
    var g = jQuery('#Grid2');
   var usersList = data;
   var totalRecords= jQuery('#Grid2').jqGrid('getGridParam','records');
   alert('Grid records' +totalRecords);
    if (usersList!=null) {
        g.jqGrid('clearGridData',false);            
       for(var i=0;i<=usersList.length;i++){
           // g.jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,usersList[i]);  
            g.jqGrid('addRowData',totalRecords+1,usersList[i]);
            totalRecords += 1;       
          // g.jqGrid('addRowData',0,usersList);        
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: please help... the records are getting added to the Second Grid grid2 but they are replaced when I add the another set of records/rows or a single row also from the first grid grid1

Answer (score 1):

The call to `clearGridData` is removing the old rows from the grid. From the [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods):

> **clearGridData**
>
> Clears the currently loaded data from grid. If the clearfooter parameter is set to true, the method clears the data placed on the footer row.

If you only want to append data, you should be able to just remove this line of code. Or am I missing something?

Comment: hi.. Thanks for the reply..i have set the clearGridriData to false. however, the new records added on the next try from Grid1 are replacing the earlier added records in Grid2. I am not sure what I am missing .. plz help

Comment: The `false` parameter to clearGridData` only controls the footer: `If the clearfooter parameter is set to true, the method clears the data placed on the footer row`. It would still clear all of the rows from the grid.